# 5. Longest Palindromic Substring. Thoery question. computersci/leetcode

Tags: computer-science

I am doing the Longest Palindromic Substring question on leetcode, and a lot of video suggest using the expanding from center to solve this problem. However, I dont really understand their theory. please help me understand their theory, thanks.

what if my string is "abadefg" or "gfedaba" then it wouldnt make sense to do odd/even starting from center?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the algorithm.

The simplest form of Manacher's algorithm takes a string like `abadefg` and converts it into `a*b*a*d*e*f*g`.  It then works left-to-right and asks the question "What is the longest palindrome that has this character as the center".   When you're done, you figure out what the longest palindrome you found overall, and remove the asterisks.

There is an alternate form of the algorithm that doesn't need to add the asterisks.  Instead it makes two passes over the string, once to find even-length palindromes and once to find odd-length palindromes.  But neither "starts at the center".

Searching the Web and Youtube for Manacher's algorithm will find you many good articles and explanations.